# Fastboot connection problem

Tags: adb, twrp, fastboot, lineageos, gapps

I am trying to install Lineage OS 16.0 on my Moto 4X. I unlocked the OEM bootloader. But when I enter the command 'fastboot reboot bootloader' it shows
'< waiting for any device >'. There it stays until I break.

The next day it suddenly worked and I booted TWRP, install Lineage OS, G-Apps 9.0 micro and started the phone following the instructions at https://wiki.lineageos.org/devices/payton/install.

Lineage seem to work fine, but the G-Apps are nowhere to be found. I remember during the installation there was an error like 'can't access date/media., such a Directory does not exist' but it worked, or I thought that it did. I wanted to reinstall it all. Now I have the same problem again.

```
C:\adb>adb devices
List of devices attached
ZY224KGGGC      device

C:\adb>fastboot reboot bootloader
< waiting for any device >
```

USB debugging is enabled, the drivers on the PC are the newest from the Motorola website.

I used every USB port on my PC.

I tried my PC and two other laptops, all Windows 10.

Also I tried CMD, Powershell, and GIT-Bash for the commands. It’s always the same response. So I don't know what to do right now.

Does someone know where that problem came from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing up `adb` and `fastboot`.

When a device is booted and visible via `adb` it can't be accessed via `fastboot` (and the other way around). Fastboot is only active while the bootloader is active.

Hence if your device is visible via `adb devices` you have to access it via `adb`.

If you want to switch to fastboot mode have to boot boot to bootloader mode by executing `adb reboot bootloader`.

Then you can use fastboot.

Comment: thanks for the answer.